# Android orientation won't change after first turn

Tags: android, orientation

I'm making a simple screen which starts on portrait orientation. After switching to landscape orientation for the first time, it works perfectly.
Though when I try switching back to portrait the screen stays on landscape.

Any ideas of what's going on?

Manifest code of that "one" activity

```
 <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="Login"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.DCWebMakers.Vairon.LOGINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: This XML says that your app will take care of orientation changes. So it will be more helpful for you to show the code where you do so.  Althoug if you target API 13+, you should also handle screenSize

Comment: My activity is not handling orientation changes, is this causing it to stay as a landscape orientation?

Answer (score 3):

Your manifest is lying to Android.  Your `android:configChanges` states that your app will handle orientation changes, and yet it does not.  [Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config):

> android:configChanges
>
> Lists configuration changes that the activity will handle itself. When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. Instead, the activity remains running and its onConfigurationChanged() method is called.
>
> Note: Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last-resort. Please read [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.

Answer (score 0):

There's a known [long-standing emulator bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189) that exhibits this one-time switch behavior--so if you are using the emulator, that could explain the problem.

To explain the first orientation switch, I would think that either:

1. You're not actually on the `LoginActivity` when you did the switch, but another activity that doesn't have the `configChanges="orientation...` flag set.
2. Or maybe you did the orientation change prior to starting the app, such as from the homescreen.  Then your app started up in landscape and wouldn't respond when you try to change orientation.